# How to effectively line up tkinter widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been a programmer for 40 years, but mostly command-line and system programming. I am converting a tcl/tk gui that I wrote to Python because much of the stuff I did in shell scripts can be done effectively in Python, but I'm having a bit of trouble making the wigets line up (using grid) the way I want them. In my example, note the buttons line up perfectly. But the label/entry widget pairs are not lining up the way I want them: Note the workspace/project in row 3. I want the label to be adjacent to the entry widget and center. Also at the bottom I would like to have the scroll text widen to it fills the width of the screen. I just need a couple of pointer, maybe how best to group things in multiple frames. Also, I am assuming that the grid rows and columns are relational to the root windows and not the frame.

```
"""
PYGUITEST - This is a GUI test to test alignments of fields
Author: Jerry Feldman
"""
import sys
import os
import Tix
import tkMessageBox
import ScrolledText
import getpass
from Tkconstants import *

class pyguitest:

    def __init__(self):
        self.mainWindow = Tix.Tk()
        self.mainWindow.tk.eval('package require Tix')

    def __createUI(self, mainWindow):
        mainWindow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.OnExitWindow)
###### major class variables
        self.username = getpass.getuser()
        self.topFrame = Tix.Frame(self.mainWindow)
        self.topRight = Tix.Frame(self.mainWindow)

### define buttons
        self.butn01 = Tix.Button(self.topFrame,text=u"Butn01",
                                command=self.OnButn01ButtonClick)
        self.butn02 = Tix.Button(self.topFrame,text=u"Butn02",
                                command=self.OnButn02ButtonClick)
        self.butn03 = Tix.Button(self.topFrame,text=u"Butn03",
                                command=self.OnButn03ButtonClick)
        self.butn04 = Tix.Button(self.topFrame,text=u"Butn04",
                                command=self.OnButn04ButtonClick)
        self.butn05 = Tix.Button(self.topFrame,text=u"Butn05",
                                command=self.OnButn05ButtonClick)
        self.butn06 = Tix.Button(self.topFrame,text=u"Butn06",
                                command=self.OnButn06ButtonClick)
        self.butn07 = Tix.Button(self.topFrame,text=u"Butn07",
                                command=self.OnButn07ButtonClick)
        self.butn08 = Tix.Button(self.topFrame,text=u"Butn08",
                                command=self.OnButn08ButtonClick)
        self.Butn09 = Tix.Button(self.topFrame,text=u"Butn09",
                                command=self.OnButn09ButtonClick)
        self.kwit = Tix.Button(self.topRight,text=u"quit !",
                                command=lambda:self.mainWindow.destroy())
### Set up the buttons grids for row 0
        self.butn01.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky="nw")
        self.butn02.grid(column=1,row=0, sticky="nw")
        self.butn03.grid(column=2,row=0, sticky="nw")
        self.butn04.grid(column=3,row=0, sticky="nw")
        self.butn05.grid(column=4,row=0, sticky="nw")
        self.butn06.grid(column=5,row=0, sticky="nw")
        self.butn07.grid(column=6,row=0, sticky="nw")
        self.butn08.grid(column=7,row=0, sticky="nw")
        self.Butn09.grid(column=8,row=0, sticky="nw")
        self.topFrame.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=8,sticky="NW")
        self.kwit.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky="NE")
        self.topRight.grid(column=10,row=1,columnspan=1,sticky="NE")

        Tix.Label(mainWindow,text="This label should be centered").grid(row=2,sticky="nwes",columnspan=8)
        wsFrame=Tix.Frame(mainWindow).grid(row=3, columnspan=9)
        Tix.Label(wsFrame,text="Workspace:").grid(row=3,column=0, sticky="e")
        wsEntry=Tix.Entry(wsFrame)
        ws="/home/myuser/workspaces/pyguitest"
        wsEntry.config(width=len(ws))
        wsEntry.insert(0, ws)
        wsEntry.grid(row=3, column=1)
        Tix.Label(wsFrame,text="Project: ").grid(row=3,column=2, sticky="e")
        self.prEntry=Tix.Entry(wsFrame)
        pr=ws+"/project"
        self.prEntry.grid(row=3,column=3, sticky="w")
        self.prEntry.insert(0, pr)
        self.prEntry.config(width=len(pr)+1)
        Tix.Label(mainWindow,text="This should also be centered" ).grid(row=4,columnspan=8)
        Tix.Label(mainWindow, text="ProductHome: ").grid(row=5)
        ProductHome="/pmount/groupname/ProductHome/homeversion"
        self.ProductHomeEntry = Tix.Entry(self.mainWindow)
        self.ProductHomeEntry.delete(0, END)
        self.ProductHomeEntry.insert(0, ProductHome)
        self.ProductHomeEntry.configure(width=len(ProductHome)+1)
        self.ProductHomeEntry.grid(row=5, column=1)
        Tix.Label(mainWindow, text="Starting Port: ").grid(row=5,column=3, sticky="e")
        portEntry=Tix.Entry(mainWindow)
        portEntry.grid(row=5,column=4, sticky="w")
        startingPort="20000"
        portEntry.insert(0,startingPort)
        portEntry.config(width=len(startingPort)+1)
        Tix.Label(mainWindow, text="Product Version: ").grid(row=5,column=5, sticky="e")
        pVersion="10.12.8 beta"
        self.productVersionEntry=Tix.Entry(mainWindow)
        self.productVersionEntry.grid(row=5, column=6, sticky="w")
        self.productVersionEntry.insert(0, pVersion)
        self.productVersionEntry.config(width=len(pVersion))
        Tix.Label(mainWindow,text="Another centered label").grid(row=6, columnspan=8)
        Tix.Label(mainWindow, text="Delta:").grid(row=7, column=0)
        delta=ProductHome+"/delta"
        self.deltaEntry=Tix.Entry(mainWindow)
        self.deltaEntry.insert(0, delta)
        self.deltaEntry.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky="w")
        self.deltaEntry.configure(width=len(delta))
        Tix.Label(mainWindow, text="Job to run: ").grid(row=7, column=2, sticky="e")
        defaultJob=ProductHome+"/jobs/default.sh"
        self.jobToRunEntry=Tix.Entry(mainWindow)
        self.jobToRunEntry.grid(row=7, column=3, sticky="w")
        self.jobToRunEntry.delete(0,END)
        self.jobToRunEntry.insert(0, defaultJob)
        self.jobToRunEntry.config(width=len(defaultJob))
        defaultLauncher=ProductHome+"/launcher/default.sh"
        Tix.Label(mainWindow, text="Launcher: ").grid(row=7, column=4, sticky="e")
        self.launcherEntry=Tix.Entry(mainWindow)
        self.launcherEntry.grid(row=7, column=5, sticky="w")
        self.launcherEntry.delete(0,END)
        self.launcherEntry.insert(0, defaultLauncher)
        self.launcherEntry.config(width=len(defaultLauncher))

        self.logger = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(self.mainWindow,
                                                width = 160,
                                                height = 60,
                                                wrap=Tix.WORD,
                                                relief="sunken")
        self.logger.grid(row=10,columnspan=8)



    def doLog(self, file):
        for line in file.read().splitlines():
            self.logger.insert(END, line+"\n")
        txt.insert(END, "\nEnd of command\n\n")



    def startpyguitest(self):
        self.__createUI(self.mainWindow)
        self.mainWindow.mainloop()

## Button Actions
    def OnExitWindow(self):
        self.mainWindow.destroy()

    def OnButn01ButtonClick(self):
        pass

    def OnButn02ButtonClick(self):
        pass

    def OnButn03ButtonClick(self):
        pass

    def OnButn04ButtonClick(self):
        pass

    def OnButn05ButtonClick(self):
        pass

    def OnButn06ButtonClick(self):
        pass

    def OnButn07ButtonClick(self):
        pass

    def OnButn08ButtonClick(self):
        pass

    def OnButn09ButtonClick(self):
        pass


    def logIt(self, stdout):
        for line in stdout.read().splitlines():
            self.logger.insert(END, line+"\n")
            self.logger.see(END)


if __name__ == "__main__":  
   pyguitest = pyguitest()
   pyguitest.startpyguitest()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make more use of the `sticky` option. There are a few widgets -- such as the scrolled text widget -- where they aren't told to stick to the edges of their cell.

You'll also want to use the `grid_rowconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure` methods to get your GUI to resize properly.

You are incorrect about the grid rows and columns. They are relative to the frame. For example, you can have things in column 0 of an inner frame, and have that inner frame at column 2 of the root window.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I have found that the sticky option works within a column, but in the case of the Workspace label and the wsEntry widget, I have sticky="e" on the label and I have added sticky="w" on the entry. I'll try your suggestions. My initial issue is to get the workspace and project pairs to center with 1 space between the labels and entry (which sticky fixes) and 1 space between the wsEntry and the Project label. Should I bunch them all up in the same frame. Note that the following lines are not.

Comment: I added sticky="nwes" on the scrolled text and it resized it properly. But, WRT: the wsFrame and its 4 members. I changed the row=3 to row=0 on the Workspace label, wsEnTry,Project label, and prEntry, and they were all inserted at the top of the main Window above the buttons. I also added in_=wsFrame to those widgets.

Comment: One more thing. The line:
    wsFrame=Tix.Frame(mainWindow).grid(row=3, columnspan=9)
Should NOT have the grid attached to it. S/B:
    wsFrame=Tix.Frame(mainWindow)
    wsFrame.grid(row=3, columnspan=9)
This is why the rows/columns on the widgets are not relative to the frame in my code. That was just a stupid on my part.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a .grid

```
btn.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

(change the #s as needed)

Comment: your answer doesn't make any sense -- the OP is already using `grid`, so your answer doesn't help at all. I appreciate the fact that you're a new stackoverflow users, but try to refrain from adding answers that don't offer much actual help. Telling them to use something they are already using doesn't get them any closer to a solution.

Comment: Sorry its really late where i live and i just had eye sudgrey so i can't see well